# Crash browser when append too much html by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

I have a html page and using jQuery append new `tr` tag from content html of `script` tag.

Content html of `script` tag have too much html and when append a few times for `table`, browser tab will crash.

I have a description at https://jsbin.com/vufeyaz/2/edit?html,js,output

How to it can working?

Answer (score 1):

Basically, everything is OK with your code. I think browser is just having troubles rendering all this HTML, and the number of times you are able click on `Add Hero` button depends on your computer's performance.

Also your approach isn't quite right. Try looking at [Angular](http://angular.io) or something like this. By the way, you don't need to `return false;`

But if you stick to native JS, then add an `id` to `<tbody>` like `<tbody id="t-body-id">` and replace the call `$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('tbody').append(content);`  with `$('#t-body-id').append(content);`

Comment: Thank for answer and ideas. I tested on a few computer. I think i will handling popup and add hero on different code